# How to update text between two delimiters multiple times in a String

Tags: python, parsing, text

I'm trying to improve some of my workflow for my writing gig. Part of it is to format the articles appropriately before submitting, and I've decided to automate some of this process -- but, I'm a little stuck. I verbally dictate the articles for efficiency, and if I can automate the formatting, it'd be a great time-savings.

I have to include headers within the article, which is the tricky part. So, I've delimited the headers from the rest of the article text by putting '[' and ']' to demarcate where they start and end. I then add their H2 tags and capitalize the necessary words. What I'm struggling with is finding the best way to find them in the String (they'll happen randomly) and replacing them with their equivalent, capitalized substring, and with the delimiters ('[' and ']') exchanged for H2 tags.

I see a lot of RegEx solutions, but I'm not sure how I'd modify the string with a different function, then use it. I'm looping through the characters, one-by-one, looking for the delimiters. How would you approach this?

For example, I'd have this as an article text and a header dictating a new paragraph, but it's all within one string:

"Color has an effect on people's mood. Choosing the right hue for your paint can entirely alter a room's atmosphere. [Welcoming your guests with color] If you're a frequent host or hostess of parties, you should consider an inviting color."

[Welcoming your guests with color] would be extracted, capitalized, and flanked by  tags. As: [h2]Welcoming Your Guests With Color[\h2]

```
def parse_for_headers(self):
    index = 0
    index_one = 0
    index_two = 0

    for char in self.input_text:
        if char == header_signal_start:
            index_one = index

        if char == header_signal_end:
            index_two = index

            header = self.input_text[index_one:index_two]
            header = self.capitalize_words(header)
            header = self.make_h2(header)
            self.input_text = self.input_text[:index_one] + header + self.input_text[index_two:]

        index += 1
```

It gives a rough output of what I want, but is this the best way to go about doing things? I feel like it's super sloppy.

I've edited it a little further.

```
def parse_for_headers(self):
    index = 0
    index_one = 0

    for char in self.input_text:
        if char == header_signal_start:
            index_one = index

        if char == header_signal_end:
            index_two = index

            header = self.input_text[index_one + 1:index_two]
            header = self.capitalize_words(header)
            header = self.make_h2(header)
            self.input_text = self.input_text[:index_one] + '\n\n' + header + '\n' + self.input_text[index_two + 1:]

        index += 1
```

Output:

Color has an effect on people's mood. Choosing the right hue for your paint can entirely alter a room's atmosphere.

[H2]Welcoming Your Guests With Color[/H2]

If you're a frequent host or hostess of parties, you should consider an inviting color.

Comment: Can we see your code attempt @discreteboy

Comment: @CiaranOBrien, hey - sorry - I've posted what I have thus far. It's pretty sloppy, and I'd like to improve upon it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
test = "[Welcoming your guests with color] would be extracted, capitalized, and [flanked] by tags."

# finds the portion of text between square brackets
result = re.findall(r'\[.*?\]', test) 

final = []
for i in result:
    # Remove brackets
    i = (i.replace('[', ''))
    i = (i.replace(']', ''))
    # Capitalise. First split the words in the sentence, capitalise, and rejoin
    i = i.split(" ") 
    i = ' '.join([word.capitalize() for word in i])   
    # Add tags
    i = "[h2]" + i + "[\h2]"
    # Store results in a list
    final.append(i)
```

You could try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def find_headings(text):
  regex = r"\[(.*?)\]"
  return [f"[h2]{heading.group().title()}[/h2]" for heading in re.finditer(regex, text)]
```